# Round Decimal Value and remove 0. or 0.0 from the Value in PHP

Tags: php

Below is my code

```
$number1 = "0.125";
$number2 = "0.05";
echo $total1 = round($number1,2);
echo $total2 = round($number2,2);
```

What I'm getting as output has

```
0.13 ---- output I want is : 13
0.05 ---- output I want is : 5
```

not getting the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$number1 = "0.125";
$number2 = "0.05";
$total1 = round($number1,2) * 100;
$total2 = round($number2,2) * 100;

echo $total1 . "\n" .$total2;
```

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1c3b84752e63fc80f51e2cd219d64f16a11d75b3)

Comment: Is this a college project ?